# OpenAM login process states

Tags: authentication, process, module, state, openam

I'm facing troubles on making IE8 to work with OpenAM. I'm using a customized login module which is a java class extending com.sun.identity.authentication.spi.AMLoginModule. My login module works perfectly with firefox, chrome and recent versions of IE, but IE8 make it work wrong.

The login module works in two steps: first it prompts for username and password, and then it prompts for verification code. The two steps of authentication process are based on process states. Therefore my process() method can be summarized like:

```
public int process(Callback[] callbacks, int state) throws AuthLoginException {
  switch (state) {
    case 1:
      return processState1(callbacks);
      break;
    case 2: 
      return processState2(callbacks);
      break;
  }

  return -1; // -1 indicates success
}
```

In most case, process() is called with state "1" after first POST (username/password) and with state "2" after second POST (verification code). But with IE8, the method is called twice with state "1" (but with different callbacks).

So my question is: do you know how the "state" argument of the process() method is managed ?  In order words, what does make this argument increase between login steps ?
Kwnowing how it is managed internally may help me to fix this problem with IE8.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage the 'state' in the module itself ..., so after you got the initial credentials (and verified them) you set the state to '2'.

OpenAM internally recognizes the new 'state' of the auth-module when the browser comes back as it provides the 'AMAuthCookie' which represents the 'authentication session' on client side.

Comment: Thank you alot. So I guess that IE8 doesn't send the AMAuthCookie correctly (maybe due tu IE8 security settings). I'll search this way by analysing HTTP requests.